# CSS Menu URL's not directing appropriately

Tags: php, css, url, menu, hyperlink

I created a CSS menu, to use on a PHP site, but now I realised that for example:

From the Home tab (URL **localhost/site**), all the item links are correct if you hover over them, but now i navigate to "Stock" for example, who's URL is **localhost/site/stock**... it opens correctly. So from Stock i want to navigate to Sales (**localhost/site/sales**), the URL of sales become **localhost/site/stock/sales** and not just **localhost/site/sales**.

I added this menu only recently, the previous one was working fine, so for a test, i replaced the css menu with the previous one, but to no avail. the problem still persist, so I assume that something else must have changed the behaviour of the links...

I can probably fix this by added " **../** " in front of the menu's URL, but on the other hand. not all items are just one step back.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using absolute URLs.

When your link is on a page located at `localhost/site/stock`:

```
<a href="sales">Link</a> <!-- goes to localhost/site/stock/sales -->
```

But if you prepend a forward slash, the destination will be absolute, relative to your document root:

```
<a href="/sales">Link</a> <!-- goes to localhost/site/sales -->
```

Assuming of course that your document root is `localhost/site`

More likely your links will have to look something like:

```
<a href="/site/sales">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in saying you need to add slashes. My suggestion would be to provide absolute links from / to your page:

```
/site
/site/sales
/site/sales/sale24
/site/stock
/site/stock/secondstockpage
/site/stock/thirdpage
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the menu as you suggested, but now, it works as follow:

if i for example set my menu link to direct to: **/site/sales/sold.php**
so the menu.php file link would look like this:

```
<li><a href="sales/">Sales</a></li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="sold.php">Sold Items</a></li>
    </ul>
```

it would sometime direct to **/site/sales/sold.php** and the next moment, it repeats the menu's directory like: **/site/sales/sales/sold.php**

so i removed the **sales** directory, as its directing there by itself, worked for a little while and now it directs to **/site/sold.php** which does not exist so it ends up with a 404.

should i specify a siteroute somewhere else?

this is very weird to me. first time i encounter something like this!

Hope my examples make sense!